# Python Bot using PRAW started returning an error "recived 403 HTTP response"

Tags: python-3.x, tweepy, praw

I am writing a twitter bot that is supposed to take the top in the hot posts section of reddits r/dankmemes, find the .png file, download it then post it to twitter using tweepy. I am not a very experienced coder and this is my first real project. I have had other issues that I have found answers on google, but this one has got me stumped. The part of the code that is throwing the error was working fine until I added the os.path.join() command into this line
`urllib.request.urlretrive(reddit_image_url, os.path.join('~/t-r_dankmemes__bot/jpg_folder', submission.title + '.jpg'))`

Now it throws this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t-r_dankmemes_bot.py", line 25, in <module>
    for submission in hot_dankmemes:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/praw/models/listing/generator.py", line 52, in __next__
    self._next_batch()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/praw/models/listing/generator.py", line 62, in _next_batch
    self._listing = self._reddit.get(self.url, params=self.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/praw/reddit.py", line 367, in get
    data = self.request('GET', path, params=params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/praw/reddit.py", line 472, in request
    params=params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/prawcore/sessions.py", line 179, in request
    params=params, url=url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/prawcore/sessions.py", line 110, in _request_with_retries
    data, files, json, method, params, retries, url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/prawcore/sessions.py", line 95, in _make_request
    params=params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/prawcore/rate_limit.py", line 32, in call
    kwargs['headers'] = set_header_callback()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/prawcore/sessions.py", line 139, in _set_header_callback
    self._authorizer.refresh()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/prawcore/auth.py", line 328, in refresh
    password=self._password)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/prawcore/auth.py", line 138, in _request_token
    response = self._authenticator._post(url, **data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/prawcore/auth.py", line 31, in _post
    raise ResponseException(response)
prawcore.exceptions.ResponseException: received 403 HTTP response
```

I'm sorry if this question is dumb, as I said I'm new to coding except for the very basic java course I took at school last year. Also if somebody could also explain how to "read" error messages like this so I can trace back where the issue is myself next time, I would appreciate it.

```
import praw
import tweepy
import urllib
import os

###reddit API setup (praw)###
reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id = '******', client_secret = ******', username = '*******', password = '******', user_agent = '******')

subreddit = reddit.subreddit('dankmemes')

hot_dankmemes = subreddit.hot(limit = 5)

###twitter API setup (tweepy)###
ckey = '******'
csecret = '******'
akey = '*******'
asecret = '******'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(akey, asecret)

TWEEPYAPI = tweepy.API(auth)

###MAIN###
for submission in hot_dankmemes:
        print('Checking ' + submission.title)
        if submission.ups >= 5000:
                print('Found Post')
                print('Checking for image in ' + submission.title)
                with urllib.request.urlopen(submission.shortlink) as pageurl:
                        for line in pageurl:
                                line = line.decode('utf-8')
                                if 'data-url=' in line:
                                        print('Found Image')
                                        reddit_image_url = line[line.index('data-url="') + 10:line.index('\" data-permalink=')]
                                        print(reddit_image_url)
                                        urllib.request.urlretrive(reddit_image_url, os.path.join('~/t-r_dankmemes__bot/jpg_folder', submission.title + '.jpg'))
                                        image_path = str('~/t-r_dankmemes_bot/jpg_folder/' + submission.title + '.jpg')
                                        TWEEPYAPI.update_with_media(image_path)
                                        print('Image successfully posted')
                                        break
                print('Post did not contain image')
                break
```

Thank you for your time, Tristan :)

Comment: A 403 error indicates that you're lacking permission to access the url/file/folder. Trying Googling "What is a 403 error."

Comment: I have no idea why it is giving me an error with that line because it worked fine until I added something that shouldn't have anything to do with PRAW

Comment: I tried running this code myself, commenting out the tweepy bit, and it worked fine. What version of python are you using?